# Why do my UICollectionView support methods only invoke when my ViewController is set as Initial View Controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, presentviewcontroller

I have a very simple ViewController called **CViewController** with a basic **UICollectionView** inside of it.

When I make **CViewController** the **Initial View Controller**, everything works fine and my UICollectionView populates itself as planned. *No problems there in the slightest.*

When I try to *modally present* **CViewController** from any other ViewController, the UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, and the UICollectionViewDelegateFlow protocols **never invoke**.

I simply get the classic "black hole" that appears when a UICollectionView is never populated with data. None of the expected delegate methods are being called according to my log, yet the CViewController is definitely being alloc'd, init'd, and loaded according to my log.

What could possibly be causing this bug? It seems so weird that I can simply flip CViewController's **"Is Initial View Controller"** property on the Storyboard and suddenly have the supported methods get called.

Here's the method I'm using to initiate the segue from a separate VC:

```
-(void)initCustomSegue
{
CViewController *newvc = [[CViewController alloc] init];
newvc.images = arrayOfImages;
newvc.distances = arrayOfDistances;
newvc.usernames = arrayOfUsers;
[self presentViewController:newvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I believe my class declaration is correctly formed:

```
@interface CViewController : UIViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
```

*(Note: You don't need to redeclare the UICollectionViewDelegate because it is a subdelegate of UICollectionDelegateFlowLayout)*

And I believe I'm setting up everything in ViewDidLoad the correct way:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
NSLog(@"loaded cviewcontroller");
[super viewDidLoad];
[self.myCollectionView setDataSource:self];
[self.myCollectionView setDelegate:self];
[self.myCollectionView registerClass:[CollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier];
[self.myCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CollectionViewCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]
        forCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier];
}
```

Since this code does work in some context you can safely assume that all of my variables are instantiated correctly and that all of my data is legit.

Any idea where I'm going wrong? I'm stumped.

EDIT:

My current workaround is to embed the original VC inside a Navigation Controller and then create a push segue in the storyboard from the original VC to the instance of CViewController on the storyboard.

I then tweaked my data-passing implementation and segue call so that I simply make a call to performSegueWithIdentifier: and then pass all of the variables in using the prepareForSegue: method.

This works but I'm still very curious what my original problem was exactly.

Comment: You get the "black hole" because you're not instantiating the controller you made in the storyboard by using alloc init to create it. You should read the "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS" so you'll understand Apple's paradigms.

Comment: @rdelmar I'm getting a black hole from the UICollectionView not the instance of CViewController itself. I know how to instantiate a view, and I my console is logging that viewDidLoad is being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that when you are presenting the ViewController, you're not using the Storyboard for instantiation, thus the outlets nor the view are not connected.

In the Storyboard, give your ViewController an identifier, and then use it to instantiate the ViewController from your storyboard. Something like this:

[image: Set the identifier in the Storyboard]

```
-(void)initCustomSegue
{
   CViewController *newvc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Identifier"];
   newvc.images = arrayOfImages;
   newvc.distances = arrayOfDistances;
   newvc.usernames = arrayOfUsers;
   [self presentViewController:newvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

However, if you know that your ViewController is and will always be the initial of that Storyboard, you don't need to do the above, just use:

```
CViewController *newvc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil] instantiateInitialViewController];
```

Comment: I believe this would solve the problem. I'll try this out tomorrow and let you know if it works.

So you think that even though my VC in the Storyboard is of type CViewController I still can't simply init+allocate an instance of the CViewController in the presenting VC, I actually have to grab view controller by it's identifier in the Storyboard? Interesting. I hadn't even thought of that.

Comment: Yes, since the Storyboard in question contains the View hierarchy and outlets that you have set up. Also, when instantiating a ViewController from a Storyboard, the initWithCoder: method is the initialiser that gets called.

Comment: Yes! It worked! It's so funny how easy it is to conceptually misunderstand things when heavily using the storyboard. Thank you so much for your answer, now I can actually have a Modal segue instead of a Push. And that makes perfect sense too, even though the CViewController class has IBOutlets and whatnot set up with the Storyboard, it's the Storyboard's version of CViewController which I wanted to instantiate, not the raw class's version.

Comment: Yes! Glad to hear that you understand the concept, and not just copy paste the code as some other people would do. Would you mind marking this answer as correct? :)